# Julia multithreading "broadcast return"

Tags: multithreading, julia

I am new to the world of multithreading, I just want to write a function that compare (large) sorted 2D arrays:

```
function check_duplicates(sites, generated_structures)
    for i in eachindex(generated_structures)
        sites == generated_structures[i] && return false
    end
    return true
end
```

"generated_structures" might be large (5M+ elements) and to speed up things I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
function check_duplicates(sites, generated_structures)
    Threads.@threads for i in eachindex(generated_structures)
        sites == generated_structures[i] && return false
    end
    return true
end
```

So that multiple threads check subparts of the large array. Is it possible that as soon as the condition is satisfied the function stops and return false? Right now some threads return true because the subpart they checked didn't contain matches.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to have a common status flag that each thread can access and bail out if some other thread has found a match. To do this in a thread-safe manner, there is `Threads.Atomic`:

```
function hasdup(val, itr)
    status = Threads.Atomic{Bool}(false)
    Threads.@threads for x in itr
        status[] && break
        (x == val) && (status[] = true)
    end
    return status[]
end
```

Now, I'm not really sure why the access to `status` needs to be thread-safe, since it will only be written to in order to set it to `true`. Removing the `Atomic` wrapper still works, but is quite a bit slower.

I get a decent threading speedup from the above code, but the threading overhead is quite large, so if your match is early in the record, the threaded version will be much slower.

A multi-threading library that has much lower overhead is Polyester.jl, which will be much faster if the match comes early. It is, however, not compatible with the Threads library, so you cannot nest it within Threads.